# get_the_date with using get_adjacent_post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show post date in get_adjacent_post. But get_the_date($prevpost->ID) shows post_id.

It can show thumbnail and title.

```
<?php
   $prevpost = get_adjacent_post(true, '', true); 
   $nextpost = get_adjacent_post(true, '', false);
   if( $prevpost or $nextpost ){ 
   ?>
<div class="cat_paging">
   <div class="row">
      <?php
         if ( $prevpost ) {
             echo '<div class="col-sm-6">
                 <div>Before</div>
                 <a href="' . get_permalink($prevpost->ID) . '">' . 
                 get_the_post_thumbnail($prevpost->ID, 'thumbnail') . '</a><p>' . 
                 get_the_title($prevpost->ID) . '</p><p>' . get_the_date($prevpost->ID) . '</p>
                 </div>';
         } else {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><a href="' . network_site_url('/') . '">TOP</a>
         </div>';
         }
         if ( $nextpost ) {
             echo '<div class="col-sm-6">
                 <div>Next</div>
                 <a href="' . get_permalink($nextpost->ID) . '">' . 
                 get_the_post_thumbnail($nextpost->ID, 'thumbnail') . '</a><p>' . 
                 get_the_title($nextpost->ID) . '</p><p>' . get_the_date($nextpost->ID) . '</p>
                 </div>';
         } else {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><a href="' . network_site_url('/') . '">TOP</a>
         </div>';
         }
         ?>
   </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Somebody knows any idea, please teach me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_the_date()` accepts two arguments, a format string and a post.

You're passing the post ID in as the first argument instead of the second.

Correct usage:

```
get_the_date( '', $prevpost )
```

One other point to note is that I'm passing in the post object rather than the ID. You could pass in an ID however the function would then have to retrieve the post object anyway.

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much @Nathan Dawson

Answer (score 0):

use get_post_meta() instead get_the_date($nextpost->ID).Read official documentation of this function from this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)